# how to reach android device unique id?

Tags: android

I'm building an android app about something.
I want that my app cannot be copied.

in WINDOWS I can do like this:

1. get cpu id from this cmd line:

   ```
   wmic cpu get processorid
   ```
2. encrypt this code and save it into database
3. every time software opened it will checks the cpu code and the code in database.   so when software copied to another PC it will say:
   encrypted code and your cpu code does not match.

I was searching for this command in android and OOPS, there isn't any thing that work 100%.
really I don't need to use only this way(get device ID and save it and..) and if you know another way to do this work(I want that my app cannot be copied) say that.

maybe it is good to say my idea that isn't completed:
create a form for buy this app with unique username in my site.
after a user bought this app it will be download for him.
every time that user want's to open the app it connect to server and see if user is available app will work for him and make his user unavailable for next time that it will be opened in another device (NOPE.I can't do this because it isn't a different between tow android device and I haven't a unique ID);else it can not be worked.

UPD1: can [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelUuid.html)
works?

Comment: IMEI number is unique i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should generate your own uuid.**

[Google's blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) says IMEI, mac address, serial number, ANDROID_ID, all of them has a problem.

Use `java.util.UUID` instead.

Comment: after searching ; now I know that UUID isn't what I want.  
I want that have unique id for a device that doesn't change.  
java.util.UUID depends to time and random number and ...

Comment: yes. you should manage that uuid (i.e. generate and save(your server etc) uuid on first launch then restore and check later) . nothing **real** unique number in android

Comment: where I can save this code?be careful that if user copied program to another device it have to don't open.and I want that user can open the program without internet after registration.

Answer (score 0):

String android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);

Comment: it isn't unique because it will be changed after "Factory restart"