# is there a way to save database on android device that user can't copy that?

Tags: android

I want to create application that has registration step.
any one that has registered in my site can open the application and **only one device per user**
after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938736/how-to-reach-android-device-unique-id) question; now I know that there isn't any unique id for android devices and I have to generate a random ID for each device and save it.
now I have a question:how I can save this code that user (even by root access) can't edit or copy this file?
-because if user copy this file to another device it will be worked like that is registered and now one user have two device with this application.
note that when user want to register; internet most be available.but I want to user doesn't need to connect to internet after registration completed.

Comment: A user is allowed to have your app on all his/her devices.

Answer (score 1):

In software security, physical access is a major problem. If someone has an access to Android device, they can access to your database. However, there are some approaches that you can follow to reduce the access risk.

- You can encrypt the data before you store it in the DB. And, decrypt the data before you use it.
- You can store your data in the cloud instead of internal storage.

Comment: your first idea is wrong because I said they can copy the file and app will be cracked.your second idea is not possible because maybe user have not access to internet after registration.note that when user want to register; internet most be available.but I want to user doesn't need to connect to internet after registration completed.

Comment: Please note that, I didn't say its going to make it totally secure, It's going to reduce the risk. In other words, it's going to be harder to crack your app. Also, I just gave you ideas, after that you need to think a little bit. For example, there is some mechanisms that you can cache the data in local, then when the user have access to the internet, you can send data.

Comment: tanks please help me on your new idea

Answer (score -1):

You could save them to internal storage

[Android Data Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

> You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.

Comment: But rooted phones will grant you access even to system files.

Comment: I think that if you want something to be immutable in the way you are looking for, it would need to be hardware specific, something like what the manufacturers can use to identify a rooted device. I don't think that something like what you are looking for exists in the Android specification. Are you sure you need to worry about hordes of rooted users swarming your server with false new users?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm new to participating in stack overflow and will keep that in mind!

Comment: rooted phones will grant you access even to system files